# htaccess rewrite conflict between www to non-www and new directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Okay, so I have a website where we are forcing a redirect from a WWW to a non-WWW version of the site because the CMS we are using can only handle one realUrl parameter per site.

I have a generic rewrite in the system that is forcing all WWW traffic to now-WWW, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And that works fine for most pages. Now the issue I am having is this. I have a sub-directory in the site that is new and I am also redirecting all traffic from the old pages into the new sub-directory. Like so:

```
Redirect 301 /my-page/ /new-directory/my-page/
```

So what is happening is that if someone comes to **http://example.com/my-page** then they are getting properly redirected to **http://example.com/new-directory/my-page**.

BUT, if they come to **http://www.example.com/my-page** - they are being redirected to **http://example.com** but never back around to **http://example.com/new-directory/my-page**.

Any help on how to overcome this would be GREATLY appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `Redirect` directives with `mod_rewrite` rules. Have your rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^my-page(/.*)?$ /new-directory$1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems to still redirect all incoming WWW traffic back to the homepage of the site, ignoring any extra parameters.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Make sure these rules are top of any other rules.

Comment: Yes, I did both. Still no change in behavior. Every attempt to go to www.example.com/my-page always ends up redirecting to example.com as opposed to example.com/new-directory/my-page

Comment: On my Apache these rules are working fine and redirecting to `localhost/new-directory/my-page` so I suspect it is some bad config/code on your side.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'll dig around and see if something is misconfigured at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the vhost config, ensure your `ServerName` is non-www, and the www is a `ServerAilas`.